# System.InvalidCastException ошибка при приведении структурированного списка к строковому

Tags: c#

как можно преобразовать структурный список в строковый ?

Прибывал так но это приводит к ошибке System.InvalidCastException

```
struct Telnet
        {
            public string ip { get; set; }
            public string message { get; set; }
            public string model { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<string> trunkport { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<int> iindex { get; set; }
        } 
    
    List<Telnet> data_collect = new List<Telnet>();

    List<string> savetologfile = (List<string>)data_collect.Select(t => $"ip:{t.ip} \t model:{t.model} \t trunkport:{string.Join(",", t.trunkport)} \t message:{t.message}");
```

Comment: `List<string> savetologfile = data_collect.Select(...).ToList();` ?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, все работает

Comment: Если вам надо сделать из объекта некую читаемую строку, то может стоит переопределить стандартный `.ToString()`? Тогда не придется постоянно писать эту портянку формирования строки. По поводу `List<string> savetologfile` - а вы уверены, что вам нужен вообще этот "каст" в `List<string>`? Вы можете просто написать `var savetologfile = data_collect.Select(x=>x.ToString());` и все, без каких-либо кастов у вас будет `IEnumerable<string>`, по которому можно пройтись, например `foreach` и делать с данными дальше что угодно. `List<>` по сути, нужен только тогда, когда вам нужно обращение через индекс.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ зависит от контекста. Выполнить ToList()/ToArray() (материализовать перечисление в общем) безопаснее, если ожидаешь, что исходная коллекция может поменяться или если надо пройтись по результирующей коллекции несколько раз.

Comment: @tym32167 Как я и написал в своем комментарии, `а вы уверены, что вам нужен вообще этот "каст"`. Я предполагаю, что человек написал левую часть (`List<string> savetologfile =`), а потом стал думать, как написать правую, вот я говорю, что в его случае левую часть, скорей всего, можно опустить, не делая лишних `.ToList()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да я просто дополнил ваш коммент, что можно и так и эдак, и как лучше - зависит от того кода, что автор нам не показал.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ этот каст нужен чтобы записать в текстовый файл потом  File.WriteAllLines(@"save\data.csv", savetologfile);

Comment: @aelfemeli Тогда вам каст не нужен, ибо `WriteAllLines` без проблем принимает сразу `IEnumerable`. То есть вы смело можете убирать `List<string>`, убирать `.ToList()`, убирать `(List<string>)` и делать [такое](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XuRsAc).